# How do I sort results based on a specific array item in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have an array of documents that looks like this:

```
patient: {
  conditions: [
    {
      columnToSortBy: "value",
      type: "PRIMARY"
    },
    {
      columnToSortBy: "anotherValue",
      type: "SECONDARY"
    },
  ]
}
```

I need to be able to `$sort` by `columnToSortBy`, but using the item in the array where `type` is equal to `PRIMARY`. `PRIMARY` is not guaranteed to be the first item in the array every time.

How do I set my `$sort` up to accommodate this? Is there something akin to:

```
// I know this is invalid. It's for illustration purposes
$sort: "columnToSortBy", {$where: {type: "PRIMARY"}}
```

Is it possible to sort a field, but only when another field matches a query? I do not want the secondary conditions to affect the sort in any way. I am sorting on that one specific element alone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregation framework

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$patient.conditions" //reshape the data
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "patient.conditions.columnToSortBy": -1 //sort it
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "conditions": { //re group it
        "$push": "$patient.conditions"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { //project it
      "_id": 1,
      "patient.conditions": "$conditions"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OLr1nMAUt7v)